# Assign a new column that uses exponential function on the index of the numpy array dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Lets say I have an array of the below nature:

```
x = arange(30).reshape((10,3))
x
Out[52]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29]])
```

How do I add a fourth column to each of the row such that this column is an exponential function of the index number and ends up with something like this:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,   2.718281828],
   [ 3,  4,  5,   7.389056099], ,
   [ 6,  7,  8,   20.08553692],
   [ 9, 10, 11,   54.59815003 ],
   [12, 13, 14,   148.4131591],
   [15, 16, 17,  403.4287935],
   [18, 19, 20,  1096.633158 ],
   [21, 22, 23,  2980.957987],
   [24, 25, 26,  8103.083928],
   [27, 28, 29,  22026.46579]])
```

Comment: What is "the index number"? The one-based row?

Comment: Yes the index has to be on the row
so.. [0,1,2] is one row ...lets say index1


[3,4,5] is the second row..so its index2

Comment: `np.c_[x, np.exp(np.arange(1, 1 + len(x)))]`? This will cast the integers to float, though.

Comment: To make an array with 3 integer columns and one float, you have to use a compound `dtype`, and get a structured array.  Do you really want/need the mix of dtypes?

Comment: @hpaulj : infact all the values of x are floats

Answer (score 3):

Computing the exponential is easy:

```
ex = np.exp(np.arange(x.shape[0]) + 1)
```

What you want to do with it is a whole different story. Numpy doesn't allow heterogeneous arrays, unlike say pandas. So with the simple answer, your result will be `float64` (`x` is most likely `int64` or `int32`):

```
x = np.concatenate((x, ex[:, None]), axis=1)
```

An alternative is using [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), which will let you preserve the input types:

```
d = [('', x.dtype)] * x.shape[1] + [('', ex.dtype)]
out = np.empty(ex.shape, dtype=d)
```

Bulk assignment is a bit tricky, but can be done with a view obtained from the raw [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) constructor:

```
view = np.ndarray(buffer=out, dtype=x.dtype, shape=x.shape, strides=(out.dtype.itemsize, x.dtype.itemsize))
view[...] = x

np.ndarray(buffer=out, dtype=ex.dtype, shape=ex.shape, strides=(out.dtype.itemsize,), offset=x.strides[0])[:] = ex
```

A simpler approach would be to use [`recarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html), as [@PaulPanzer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869267/assign-a-new-column-that-uses-exponential-function-on-the-index-of-the-numpy-arr/52869402#comment92653267_52869402):

```
out = np.core.records.fromarrays([*x.T, ex])
```

Comment: You can construct the filled structured array directly using `rec.fromarrays` (technically, this will create a record array, but in practice I'm not aware of any differences to structured arrays) `np.rec.fromarrays([x, np.exp(np.arange(1, 11))], formats='(3,)i8,f8')`. This avoids the self harm potential of `stride_tricks`. If you don't want the three int columns lumped together you can view cast that to `'i8,i8,i8,f8'`.

Comment: @Paul. I've come up with a simpler method for not specifying the dtype for the recarray.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(30).reshape((10,3))
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1] + 1))
b[:, :-1] = a
b[:, 3] = np.exp(np.arange(len(b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a single array of powers of `e` starting at one, you can use

```
powers = np.power(np.e, np.arange(10) + 1)
```

Which basically takes the number `e` and rases it to the powers given by array `np.arange(10) + 1`, i.e. the numbers [1...10].

You can then add this as an additional column by first reshaping it and then adding it using `np.hstack`.

```
powers = powers.reshape(-1, 1)
x = np.hstack((x, powers))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct such column with:

```
>>> np.exp(np.arange(1, 11))
array([2.71828183e+00, 7.38905610e+00, 2.00855369e+01, 5.45981500e+01,
       1.48413159e+02, 4.03428793e+02, 1.09663316e+03, 2.98095799e+03,
       8.10308393e+03, 2.20264658e+04])
```

So we can first obtain the number of rows, and then use `np.hstack`:

```
rows = x.shape[0]
result = np.hstack((x, np.exp(np.arange(1, rows+1)).reshape(-1, 1)))
```

We then otain:

```
>>> np.hstack((x, np.exp(np.arange(1, 11)).reshape(-1, 1)))
array([[0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00, 2.71828183e+00],
       [3.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00, 5.00000000e+00, 7.38905610e+00],
       [6.00000000e+00, 7.00000000e+00, 8.00000000e+00, 2.00855369e+01],
       [9.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01, 1.10000000e+01, 5.45981500e+01],
       [1.20000000e+01, 1.30000000e+01, 1.40000000e+01, 1.48413159e+02],
       [1.50000000e+01, 1.60000000e+01, 1.70000000e+01, 4.03428793e+02],
       [1.80000000e+01, 1.90000000e+01, 2.00000000e+01, 1.09663316e+03],
       [2.10000000e+01, 2.20000000e+01, 2.30000000e+01, 2.98095799e+03],
       [2.40000000e+01, 2.50000000e+01, 2.60000000e+01, 8.10308393e+03],
       [2.70000000e+01, 2.80000000e+01, 2.90000000e+01, 2.20264658e+04]])
```